# Is there any way to decrypt a file create with the following command?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I create a file using:

```
gpg --cipher-algo AES256 --output file -c original_file
```

The system ask me for a paraphrase and I typed in.

So the question is: Is there any way to decrypt this file without knowing the paraphrase?

Comment: I feel this question is off-topic here. May be more suited to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently AES256 takes too long to [brute force](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279619). From the link:

> If you assume:

```
Every person on the planet owns 10 computers.
There are 7 billion people on the planet.
Each of these computers can test 1 billion key combinations per second.
On average, you can crack the key after testing 50% of the possibilities.
```

> Then the earth's population can crack one encryption key in 77,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years!

So for now: no. In 10 years computers might be able to drop this down to a fraction but then we will have something like AES512 (2 weeks ago they discovered a new prime number and those can be useful for new encryption).

But that is assuming it has no backdoors and someone does not have other methods of getting the passphrase (social engineering).

Comment: If you take the calculation from the link you provided and let the AES256 passphrase brute force from `Tianhe-2`, the fastest supercomputer in Nov '14. It would take `103,014,681,600,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` years to read the data. WOW

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is used by the US government to encrypt their top secret documents and it is called `calculation save`.

But nothing is impossible. If you have a really fast computer and a lot of time (probably a few hundred or thousand years), you can crack any password.

So, to answer your question: **Yes**, there is a way to decrypt your file without knowing the passphrase, but that would be way to expensive for anybody or any government. And possibly not in your lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to decrypt AES-encrypted contents unless

1. You invest a *vast* number of CPU hours by brute forcing it. Vast means something out of range for even powerful attackers for the next few dozen years.
2. Somebody finds problems with the AES algorithm, rendering the mathematical problem much easier to solve than it is expected (making brute force attacks feasible).
3. Quantum computing is bringing massive speedups in brute-forcing AES, but this is not to be expected within the next few years and AES 256 is still considered safe enough even if this would happen  (some consider AES 128 to be too weak for post-quantum-cryptography, though).
4. The string-to-key function used in GnuPG to derive the session key from a passphrase proves to be weak, which is also rather unlikely.

To wrap up: the data encrypted with AES 256 is safe, and probably will be safe for a few dozen years. Theoretically it would be possible to run brute-force attacks, but these are so expensive they cannot be performed.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that "quantum computing" would reduce the time to brute force *either* public key encryption *or* conventional (AES) encryption (or vice-versa?), but not necessarily both by the same factor; like one method would be practically solved overnight, but the other would only be 1000x faster...?

Comment: The different algorithms will suffer different impact. From what I read, most symmetric algorithms (including AES) will only suffer slightly, and using a large enough block will still keep them safe. Other algorithms, especially for asymmetric cryptography, suffer much higher damage. But quantum computers are still away probably quite some years. Also, crypto analysis did not put much effort in quantum algorithms yet, there might be more attacks to be described.